# Django filter queryset if a field exists

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I want to filter my queryset if and only if `loan` exists in my model `ShgGroupLoanMarking`.

```
class ShgGroupLoanMarking(models.Model):
 shg = models.ForeignKey(Shg, null=True)
 category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=GROUP_CATEGORY, default="shg_group")
 msss = models.ForeignKey(Msss, null=True)
 shgmember = models.ForeignKey(ShgMember, null=True)
 loan = models.ForeignKey(Loan, null=True)
 date_of_marking = models.DateField(null=True)
 paid = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
 loan_amount = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
 service_charge = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
 print_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 sent_to_bank_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 receipt_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
ShgGroupLoanMarking.objects.filter(loan__isnull=False)
```

or

```
ShgGroupLoanMarking.objects.exclude(loan=None)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually test whether a field exists, it assumes it exists and checks if it's null. If the field genuinely doesn't exist, this still throws a `jango.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword '....' into field.`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you know of a way to filter without triggering that error?

Comment: Getting errors is fine, you just need to make sure to have a try/except in place. The alternative (first check the model's field set, and then only filter if it contains the field you're filtering on) would take longer than to just catch the exception.